# how to parse this xml data with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, nsxmlparser

I am trying to figure out how I can parse this xml :

```
<item>
    <title>
        <![CDATA[Preview: Courtney Crumrin and the Night Things Special Edition]]>
    </title>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <pubDate>Tue, 20 Dec 2011 11:52:48 -0800</pubDate>
    <link>http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=preview&amp;id=10864</link>
    <guid>http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=preview&amp;id=10864</guid>
</item>
```

There are two issues, the structure.. there are many items, So I am thinking of creating a `NSMutableArray` with a `NSDictionary` that can hold these other values inside the item... would this be correct if so how to you pass those other values into the `NSDictionary`?

Also the other question is how do i deal with the CDATA? dose it just get ignored or do I have to do something special with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's fine to use an array of dictionaries. You'll generally want to use a mutable array of mutable dictionaries. Each time you start a new `<item>` element, create a new dictionary and start populating it as you receive subelements. When you get to the closing `</item>` tag, add the dictionary to the array.

As for the CDATA, your parser delegate should implement the `-parser:foundCDATA:` method. Then, your xml parser will simply report the data by calling that method, much as it calls `-parser:foundCharacters:` for regular character data.

Comment: how would I set didStartElement? I would use if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) to set up the mutablearray but what would I do to set up the dictionary?

Comment: The mutable array should be an instance variable on the class implementing the `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods.